# What is worth of passing string in premain method

Tags: java, jvm

As we know this is the syntax of declaring premain method in a class

```
public static void premain(String s,Instrumentation inst)
```

This method is called by JVM, so JVM passes all the parameters. Here is a string parameter passed by JVM which is null. If JVM will pass null everytime, then what is its need?

Comment: It's not always null.

Comment: See this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

from Javadoc :

> public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst);
>
> ...
>
> Each agent is passed its agent options via the agentArgs parameter.
>   The agent options are passed as a single string, any additional
>   parsing should be performed by the agent itself.

and for passing arguments to agent you should use (from Javadoc) :

> -javaagent:jarpath[=options]

when you don't specify the options (arguments), you will get null.

i encourage you reading the Javadoc page for  Java Instrumentation API :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html

Comment: Instrumentation is an advanced class to use, and anyone using it should know that reading the javadoc could be helpful. o_O +1